# Javascript - how to find hebrew?

Tags: javascript, regex, hebrew, right-to-left

i"m trying to fint if a string starts(first letter) width an RTL language/ hebrew.

any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This will find hebrew letters encoded in the [Hebrew](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hebrew.html) Unicode code point range: `[\u0590-\u05FF]`

Comment: The above is not working for me. Any chance for an example? I'm [trying this](http://jsbin.com/iXOzEHI/1/edit) and it's returning false.

Comment: @hitautodestruct This might be a bit too late, but for reference note that your code sample contains an [en dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html), **–**, instead of a hyphen, **-**. This invalidates the range of your character class and causes the pattern not to match. See [corrected example here](http://jsbin.com/wifememipo/edit).

Comment: @Boaz Thanks for this! Never too late :-)

Comment: Note that `\u2135-\u2138` and `\ufb1d-\ufb4f` are also Hebrew letters, even though they are not part of the "Hebrew" Unicode block.

Answer (score 25):

JavaScript does not support regex scripts like `\p{InHebrew}` (or something similar). However, it does support Unicode escapes, so you could use a regex like:

```
/[\u0590-\u05FF]/
```

which will match a single Hebrew character.

See: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0590.pdf
and: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 14):

```js
    function is_heb(Field) {
        // First choose the required validation

        HebrewChars = new RegExp("^[\u0590-\u05FF]+$");
        AlphaNumericChars = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$");
        EnglishChars = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\-]+$");
        LegalChars = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05FF ]+$"); //Note that this one allows space 

        // Then use it

        if (!LegalChars.test(Field)) {
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
```

```html
<input id="the_text" type="text" value="בדיקה" />
<br /><button onclick="document.getElementById('the_result').value = is_heb(document.getElementById('the_text').value)">Is it Hebrew?</button>
<br /><br />
Result:
<br /><input id="the_result" type="text">
```

Comment: Hi. This is a great code but I think I messed it up. I'm trying to check for Hebrew characters PLUS space. LegalChars doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Hi, try this: 
LegalChars = new RegExp("^[\u0590-\u05FF ]+$");
| https://codverter.com/src/webeditor

Answer (score 4):

`if (str.charCodeAt(0) >= 0x590) && (str.charCodeAt(0) <= 0x5FF) then` it is considered a hebrew character

Comment: "most probably"? I'd say "definitely" :)

Comment: Actually there are some cases where it would fail. For example, a paragraph which starts with a number is not definitely an English/LTR paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Especially for Hebrew the question is answered already - regarding all ranges:

Especially for JS I would recommend a tool to build your regex - see [Unicode range RegExp generator](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex#) (Compiles character ranges suitable for use in JavaScript)

[ just select hebrew or the scripts or ranges you want ]