# Forcing users to use a certain language as an input

Tags: html

I would like to force the user to type in a certain language in my text input.
How can I do that? Using an html form of course.

**edit** I havn't tried nothing since I have no idea how to do that. 
and the language I'm talking about is hebrew so the characters are diffrent from english(ASCII codes are diffrent).

Comment: What have you tried? And what exactly do you want to happen? This question is rather vague...

Comment: Define what that means exactly. How would you tell the difference between one language and another? Is it about a unique alphabet, or about language guessing/identification?

Comment: Display this instruction, let the user type in whatever language they want, and after validation, if the input doesn't match your criteria, display a validation error.

Comment: Miten haluat käsitellä fragments in English blandat med hebreiska?

Comment: Hebrew should actually be really easy to detect uniquely. So all you need is a typical validation Javascript snippet, of which there are plenty if you look around. The validation rule then will be a regular expression that only matches Hebrew characters, of which there should also be many examples if you look for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041859/javascript-how-to-find-hebrew) where someone had a similar issue. The solutions is a short javascript code that checks wether your text contains hebrew letters or not.

Answer (score 0):

Various options:

- In a textbox that is being validated after submit button is clicked.
- A dropdown where user selects a language
- An autocomplete textbox that enables submit button if valid language is typed or selected

Anyway, your question is not very clear.