# Add Unicode character support to a regexp expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to have this regex expression `^\W*(\w+\b\W*){12,}$` support all Russian,Arabic & Hebrew characters or if possible, have it simply support unicode.

The expression should match this text for example:

> מאז ראשית דרכנו, התמקדנו ביצירת חוויית המשתמש הטובה ביותר. גם בתכנון דפדפן חדש וגם בהוספת פריט חדש לדף הבית, אנחנו עושים מאמצים רבים כדי להבטיח שבסופו של דבר הוא ישרת אותך, ולא את המטרה או היעדים הפנימיים שלנו.

Generally, the purpose of the expression is to be able to match a text that includes at least 12 words, no matter whats the language. The regex will be used in JavaScript.

Comment: Also see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041859/javascript-how-to-find-hebrew