# How to convert a Char by the position on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, keyboard

I need a way to convert the a string, or a char, to it's equivalent on the keyboard on a different language. and as such, in hebrew, for example, "ש" will become "a" or "A".

Couldn't find the proper way to do so without creating a giant switch statement or a dictionary.

any answer on either JS or C# will be great.

Comment: _Either_ JS or C#? That’s weird… Anyway, in JavaScript you can create an object like this: `var letters={"ש":"a", "etc.":"b",…}` and so on, then use `letters["ש"]` to get `"a"`.

Comment: @Xufox The equivalent in C# can be a dictionary

Comment: well, in my app, i can write server side code in JS and in C# (using V8) so if it's easier to answer it on one or the other, then there's no need in putting up constrains.

Comment: Refer these stackoveflow answers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041859/javascript-how-to-find-hebrew

Comment: This is a more complex task than I think you realize. I believe the best way would be to provide a mapping for each character in a multidimensional array or dictionary and implement your own function (JS) or method (C#) to perform translation.

Comment: ya, i want to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: @SaharZehavi  http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case someone will look for this answer, It seems like that isn't a clear way of doing that without using a dictionary or a switch statement.

basa.

Comment: I see I'm not the only one who got frustrated enough by typing out. a whole paragraph before realizing I had Hebrew selected instead of English :)

Answer (score 2):

Use **keyCode** of the *keydown* or *keyup* events. Property of this event contains code of keyboard key but not code of symbol.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
});
```

Comment: I need a way to convert a given string (or char) and i can't access the keyboard event that generated the key.

Comment: if there is only a line, you want to convert (and no other useful information on how this line has been received), it can only be done dictionaries. By itself, the symbol has nothing to do with the key code keyboard

Answer (score 2):

here is how i do it in javascript

```
qwerty_mapping = {
"ת":"," ,",":"ת"
,"ף":";"    ,";":"ף"
,"ץ":"."    ,".":"ץ"
,"ש":"a"    ,"a":"ש"
,"נ":"b"    ,"b":"נ"
,"ב":"c"    ,"c":"ב"
,"ג":"d"    ,"d":"ג"
,"ק":"e"    ,"e":"ק"
,"כ":"f"    ,"f":"כ"
,"ע":"g"    ,"g":"ע"
,"י":"h"    ,"h":"י"
,"ן":"i"    ,"i":"ן"
,"ח":"j"    ,"j":"ח"
,"ל":"k"    ,"k":"ל"
,"ך":"l"    ,"l":"ך"
,"צ":"m"    ,"m":"צ"
,"מ":"n"    ,"n":"מ"
,"ם":"o"    ,"o":"ם"
,"פ":"p"    ,"p":"פ"
,"/":"q"    ,"q":"/"
,"ר":"r"    ,"r":"ר"
,"ד":"s"    ,"s":"ד"
,"א":"t"    ,"t":"א"
,"ו":"u"    ,"u":"ו"
,"ה":"v"    ,"v":"ה"
,"'":"w"    ,"w":"'"
,"ס":"x"    ,"x":"ס"
,"ט":"y"    ,"y":"ט"
}
function correctChar(old_char){
if(qwerty_mapping[old_char] == undefined)
    {
        return(old_char)
    } 
    else
    {
        return(qwerty_mapping[old_char])
    }
}

function correctString(old_string){
new_string = ""
for(i=0;i<old_string.length;i++){
    new_string = new_string+correctChar(old_string[i])
}
return new_string;
}
```