# How to detect Hebrew characters in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, character

I'm trying to implement a simple function of detecting whether a string contains Hebrew characters using js. HELP!

Edit: I'm not interested in detecting a rtl language, just Hebrew.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - how to find hebrew?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041859/javascript-how-to-find-hebrew)

Comment: Are you able to sort it out this? from above link?

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan Okay let me try it for you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you need to use this regular expression to search in your string .**"/[\u0590-\u05FF]/"** i.e.

```js
function contains_heb(str) {
    return (/[\u0590-\u05FF]/).test(str);
}
```

```html
<input id="the_text" type="text" value="בדיקה" />
<br /><button onclick="document.getElementById('the_output').value = contains_heb(document.getElementById('the_text').value)">Does it contain Hebrew?</button>
<br /><br />
Output:
<br /><input id="the_output" type="text" />
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.