# javascript match hebrew word inside double curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a js function that working in english but i get error in hebrew

the function match all the words in string that inside  `{{ }}` and return the word inside the double curly bracket in a `array` without the curly bracket
the string can Contains both english and non english words like this:    `{{test}} {{בדיקה}} hi this is my test {{test2}}`

```
var str_eng =  "{{test}} {{test1}}";
var str_non_eng = "{{בדיקה}} {{עעע}}";

str_eng.match(/{{\s*[\w\.]+\s*}}/g).map(function(x) { return x.match(/[\w\.]+/)[0];  }) //array[ "test","test1" ] //ok

str_non_eng.match(/{{\s*[\w\.]+\s*}}/g).map(function(x) { return x.match(/[\w\.]+/)[0];  }) // error not working
```

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `[\w\.]+` with `.*?` in the first bit, and just remove the brackets via `substr()` in your `map`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to get string between curly braces "{I want what's between the curly braces}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can you show me how? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` does not match Hebrew characters - to do that you need to match on the Unicode range for Hebrew with `[\u0590-\u05FF]` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041859/javascript-how-to-find-hebrew).

You can blend `\w` and `[\u0590-\u05FF]` to match both ASCII and Hebrew:

```js
// var str_non_eng = "{{בדיקה}} {{עעע}}";
var str_non_eng = "{{test}} {{בדיקה}} hi this is my test {{test2}}";

var r1 = /{{\s*[\w\u0590-\u05FF\.]+\s*}}/g
var r2 = /[\w\u0590-\u05FF\.]+/;

var foo = str_non_eng.match(r1).map(function(x) {
  return x.match(r2)[0];
});
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: if my string dont contains {{ }} i get error , "test test"

Comment: If your string has no `{{ }}` then you would split the code into two - `var foo = str_non_eng.match(r1);` then `if (foo) { // do the rest }`

Comment: `if ( str.indexOf("}") !== -1;  ) {  return str  }`  fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

you can't use \w for Hebrew chars.
use the following :

```
/{{\s*[\w\u0590-\u05FF\.]+\s*}}/g
```